# Stop concurrent.futures if a condition is met and then execute again after the task is done

Tags: python, json, python-requests, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

I am fetching JSON data from a website (https://www.nseindia.com/) using python request library. The website only gives data if correct cookies are provided. So I use selenium webdriver to get cookies and then get data for 850 different stocks.

Now, my code is such that if the cookies are wrong, then selenium should open again and get new cookie value. But the problem is that when I am using concurrent.futures, the tasks are very fast (due to asynchronicity) and it opens new drivers for each symbol till new cookies are not found. My code is as below:

--Initially get cookies

```
cookie_dict = get_cookies()

for cookie in cookie_dict:
        if cookie == "bm_sv" or cookie == "nsit" or cookie == "nseappid":
            session.cookies.set(cookie,cookie_dict[cookie])
```

--This function is used in Thread Pool Executor

```
def final(u):
    try:
        data = session.get(u,headers = headers).json()
        print(data['data'][0]['CH_SYMBOL'])
        list_done.append(data['data'][0]['CH_SYMBOL'])
        
    except:
        print("Error")
        cookie_dict = get_cookies()

        for cookie in cookie_dict:
            if cookie == "bm_sv" or cookie == "nsit" or cookie == "nseappid":
                session.cookies.set(cookie,cookie_dict[cookie])
        data = session.get(u,headers = headers).json()
        print(data['data'][0]['CH_SYMBOL'])
        list_done.append(data['data'][0]['CH_SYMBOL'])
```

As you can see that if exception is met, it should get new cookies. But as I previously mentioned, that futures will keep running for other stocks and exceptions will be met till new cookie is not found.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 5) as executor:
    executor.map(final,urls)
```

Is there a way I can change my code, or some built in facility by futures, so that I can stop it till I don't get new cookies and continue running only if new cookies are appended?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `wait()` method of `concurrent.futures` to monitor for the first exception. first, you have to change `final` to be throwing. You should not append to a shared list inside this function, you should return the value:

```py
def final(u):
    data = session.get(u,headers = headers).json()
    print(data['data'][0]['CH_SYMBOL'])
    return data['data'][0]['CH_SYMBOL']
```

Second, instead of using `.map()` you submit work and store futures:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(final, u) for u in urls]
```

Then you use `wait()` to wait for an exception to occur. Here, either there is an exception and you handle it before continuing, of there is no error and you unwrap the futures:

```py
from concurrent.futures import wait, FIRST_EXCEPTION

completed, not_done = wait(futures, return_when=FIRST_EXCEPTION)

if not_done:
  # An exception occurred before all futures completed,
  # handle it here.

# Here, handle the results of the futures,
# `completed` contains both finished and failed futures,
# `not_done` contains pending futures.
```

Note that you should check for each future if succeeded of failed before unwrapping it, and you should resubmit futures that failed. Also, the `wait()` function does not cancels pending futures, so `not_done` futures are still progressing.